# How can I specify a user or for a data source that is expecting kerberos

Tags: jboss, redhat-datavirt

Scenario:

- User connects to JDV without Kerberos (just name and PW)
- jndi datasource is defined to connect with domain security
- jndi datasource needs different user that is kerberos aware

how do I define the user at the datasource, when its on kerberos?

example:

```
            <datasource jndi-name="java:/K_MYSQL" pool-name="K_MYSQL" enabled="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/k_test</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <pool>
                    <allow-multiple-users>true</allow-multiple-users>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <security-domain>FUNKE.HK</security-domain>
                </security>
            </datasource>
```

Answer (score 0):

See an example for using Kerberos with Oracle here [1], follow similar instructions to MySQL. This article shows both Kerberos at the data source and as well as at Teiid JDBC layer.

[1] https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/KerberosAuthenticationToOracleFromTeiid

Comment: Thanks, will try out. Does this example also work if Teiid JDBC layer is not Kerberos, only data source (Oracle in this example, MySQL in mine)